# diff-text-hunk : Hunk text not found but patch -p0 works as intended with the same patch file

Tags: diff-mode

When I go to my hunk and use `diff-text-hunk`, I see in minibuffer and `Messages` :

```
Hunk text not found
```

or with another command :

```
diff-apply-hunk: Can’t find the text to patch
```

But if I try on terminal with `patch -d . --verbose -p0 --dry-run < mypatch.patch`
it tells me :

```
checking file MYFILE
Using Plan A...
Hunk #2 succeeded at 244 with fuzz 1. #the one i try with emacs
```

Why doesn't emacs behave as command line patch command? I do it through TRAMP if thats important.